# Adding Images from a image folder dynamically to a div box

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic

I'm trying to create a random number generator where based on the number an image is chosen from the img folder that is on the same hierarchy as the CSS folder. However the image is being chosen and being displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var addObj = {

    add: function () {
      var box = document.getElementById('box');
      var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
      var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
      var pic = document.getElementById('pic')
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
      var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
      console.log(x);
      console.log(y);
      console.log(z);
    },

    EventListners: function () {
      var button = document.getElementById('rune');
      button.addEventListener('click', addObj.add, false);

      if (addObj.add.x = 1) {
        addObj.add.box = "url('./img/fa.jpg')";
      }else {
        console.log("n/a")
      }
    }

  };

addObj.EventListners();
```

Comment: Please add the html.

Comment: addObj.add is a function, so you cannot use as element (addObj.add.x, addObj.add.box)

Comment: What do you suggest I do? Create another function? and call it in eventlistner?

Comment: I do not know, what do you want to do. If you every time want to generate new numbers, you should use  `addObj.add().x`, ` addObj.add().box`, if you want to use the generated all the way the same numbers, you should declarate the object with `var addObj={add:function() {/*function which you written*/}() , ...}` (so immidiately call the function). End of course, you should add the `return {x:x,y:y,z:z}` to the end of the function at `add`.

Comment: I want to be able to display an image based on what number is generated randomly between 1 and 18. So how do I go about that? That's why I'm using if statements

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
  var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
  var pic = document.getElementById('pic')
  // this elements you can get globally
  var addObj = {

    add: function () {
      let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
      let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
      let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
      if (x == 1) { // the checker block you should add to the function at the eventlistener, the `=` is the assignment operator, the logically operator the `==` or the `===`
      box.src = './img/fa.jpg'; // the `box` variable is an image element, you can set the source with the `src` attribute
      }else {
        console.log("n/a")
      }
    },
    EventListners: function () {
      var button = document.getElementById('rune');
      button.addEventListener('click', addObj.add, false);

    }

  };

addObj.EventListners();
```

The OOP is very nice thing, but at first you should know the language well.